# Return List<T> from Apex controller to lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

**All my code**

Saved as DX project in [my github repo](https://github.com/Xixiao007/testListReturn)

**I have a lightning component contains:**

1. client Controller function `doInit` call Apex Controller `getTree`function and print out received data in `console.log`
2. `getTree` function returns a list of `TreeNode` class with `id` and `name` attributes

**My issue is:**

I do not think @AuraEnabled is needed for `id` and `name` in `TreeNode` class. However, if I remove @AuraEnabled, they are gone in `console.log`.

For example, if I remove @AuraEnabled from `name` in `TreeNode` class,
console.log prints below, without name key:value pair anymore.

```
result: 
[
  {
    "id": "0016E00000UFOPTQA5"
  }
]
```

**Key code file (all code are saved in [my github repo](https://github.com/Xixiao007/testListReturn)**

Client controller js

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getTree");
        var cb = function(response) {
            console.log(
                "result: \n" + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue(), null, 2) + "\n"
            );
        };
        helper.apexCall(component, action, {}, cb);
    }
});
```

Apex Controller cls

```
public class testApexController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<TreeNode> getTree()
    {
        List<Account> allAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];

        List<TreeNode> tree = new List<TreeNode>();

        addAccounts(tree, allAccounts);
        System.debug('test tree nodes: ' + tree);
        return tree;
    }

    private static void addAccounts(List<TreeNode> tree, List<Account> accounts){
        for (Account a : accounts){
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(a.id, a.name);
            tree.add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

TreeNode class

```
public class TreeNode {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String id;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String name;

    public TreeNode(String id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**All my code**

Saved as DX project in [my github repo](https://github.com/Xixiao007/testListReturn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, @AuraEnabled is required for attributes to be serialized. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm):

> - Use @AuraEnabled on Apex class static methods to make them accessible as remote controller actions in your Lightning components.
> - Use @AuraEnabled on Apex instance methods and properties to make them serializable when an instance of the class is returned as data from a server-side action.

Comment: ohhh....!! Google ranks [this doc 1st](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_AuraEnabled.htm), which doesn't tell 2nd scenario in your doc....

Comment: is there any reason behind this 2nd scenario `make them serializable`? Security concern? It seems to me a futile thing.

Comment: @XiXiao I presume it's a performance thing. It allows you to have other data in the class that won't be transferred, reducing bandwidth and memory usage on the client.

Comment: IMHO, that should be up to the developer to decide (wrap needed data in one extra step and send to client) instead of using annotations.. But thanks again man :)

Comment: @XiXiao Yeah, I agree. It seems like an unnecessary extra step, but I guess it makes sense if you have a Java background.